# Atollic TrueStudio, how to unittest?

Tags: unit-testing, truestudio

I'm trying to make unit tests with Atollic TrueStudio (for STM32 microcontrollers).

In the past they had a dedicated unit test application (TrueVerifier), but I wonder what is the best way to use it now?

Also, if there is no unit test for TrueStudio, how can I use e.g. Cute Test (for C++) while under TrueStudio? It is based on Eclipse, however, when I try to install it, it seems to succeed, but I cannot select or see any option to create unit tests.